# Synchronized Data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

After installing Marketing Cloud connect and setting up Data stream, I can see my Salesforce object and data coming in Marketing cloud on Synchronised data extension. But I can not use the data for sending any emails as its not a standard data extension, can not filter it or Use it as a template to have a new Data extension created which I can populate using SQL query. What is the usability of the this data extension?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't filter it? Filters / queries are the main purpose, so you should be able to do both.

Comment: Hi Saurabh - did my answer, resolve your question? or is there more i can do to help? :)

Answer (score 10):

Synchronized Data Extensions are automatically added to your data model in contact builder. In order to actually work the data, at present, you have to manually create a new data extension and populate it with data by using SQL. (note you may have to enter "ent." in front of the FROM Table).

**/* Update */**

If you access synchronized data extensions via Email Studio, at the top right corner of a data extension you should be able to create a filtered data extension