# Synchronised Data Extension

Tags: ampscript, dataextensions, data

In SFMC I am currently trying to use data from a Synchronized data extension using ampscript. I have added the ENT. in front of its name. However, when I am trying to test it, I get the error message saying "You don't have access to that DE". I have also tested with a person who have admin right, but getting the same error message.

So I am wondering- whether its possible to use data from a synchronized data extension in an email? :)

Comment: I think this will help you.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/160845/synchronized-data-extension

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)